# How to continue the parsing after reaching the end tag of one xml node?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have the xml as below.

```
<xml>
    <!-- Labels -->


    <labels>
        <label id="lblMS">
            <text language="EN" value="Morning Sync"/>
            <text language="DE" value="Morgan Sync"/>
        </label>
        <label id="lblES">
            <text language="EN" value="Evening Sync"/>
            <text language="DE" value="Sync Abend"/>
        </label>
        <label id="lblAS">
            <text language="EN" value="Afternoon Sync"/>
            <text language="DE" value="Sync Afternoon"/>
        </label>
    </labels>

    <syncgroupsettings>
        <syncgroupset id = "sgMS" labelid = "lblMS" enabled = "YES" default = "OFF">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "VISITS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "CUSTOMERS"/>
        </syncgroupset>

        <syncgroupset id = "sgAS" labelid = "lblAS" enabled = "YES" default = "ON">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "SALESDOCS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "ANALYTICS"/>
        </syncgroupset>
    </syncgroupsettings>

</xml>
```

I'm parsing the first part of the xml, ie. labels part. When i reached the end of the labels tag, instead of going to the next node ie. syncgroupsettings it is returning the list of array with hashmap. Please find the code as below.

```
import android.util.Xml;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CountryXmlParser {

    private static final String ns = null;
    List<SyncGroupSettings> employees;
    private SyncGroupSettings employee;
    private String text;

    public CountryXmlParser() {
        employees = new ArrayList<SyncGroupSettings>();
    }

    public List<SyncGroupSettings> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    /** This is the only function need to be called from outside the class */
    public List<ArrayList<HashMap>> parse(Reader reader)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
        try{
            List<ArrayList<HashMap>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>();
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);         
            parser.setInput(reader);
            parser.nextTag();           
            return readCountries(parser);           
        }finally{

        }
    }        

    /** This method read each country in the xml data and add it to List */
    private List<ArrayList<HashMap>> readCountries(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException,IOException{

        List<ArrayList<HashMap>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "xml");

        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();         
            if(name.equals("labels")){

                //readCapital(parser);
            }
            else if(name.equals("label"))
             {
                 list.add(readCountry(parser));
             }
            else
            if(name.equals("syncgroupsettings"))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            if(name.equals("syncgroupset"))
            {
                parse(parser);
            }else

            {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        parse(parser);
        return list;
    }

    /** This method read a country and returns its corresponding HashMap construct */
    private ArrayList<HashMap> readCountry(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "label");

        String labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "id");
        String textlan = "";
        String textval="";


        ArrayList<HashMap> al=new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();
             if(name.equals("text")) {
                //  labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "id");

                textlan = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"language");
                textval = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"value");
                 String details =   "Language : " + textlan + "\n" +
                         "Value : " + textval + "\n";
                 hm.put(labelid,details );
                 al.add(hm);
                 readCapital(parser);
             }
            else
             {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }

        return al;
    }


    /** Process Capital tag in the xml data */    
    private void readCapital(XmlPullParser parser) 
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {    
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "text");
        parser.nextTag();
    }


    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) 
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
     }


    public List<SyncGroupSettings> parse(XmlPullParser parser) {
        String id = "";
        String labelid="";
        String enabled = "";
        String default1 = "";
        String syngroupname = "";

        try {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "syncgroupsettings");
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("syncgroupset")) {
                            // create a new instance of employee
                            employee = new SyncGroupSettings();
                            employees.add(employee);
                            id = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"id");
                            labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"labelid");
                            enabled = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"enabled");
                            default1 = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"default");
                            employee.setId(id);
                            employee.setLabelId(labelid);
                            employee.setSynDefault(enabled);
                            employee.setSynEnabled(default1);
                        }else
                       if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("syncgroup")) {
                            ArrayList<SyncGroupSettings.Item> syngrp =new ArrayList<SyncGroupSettings.Item>();
                            syngroupname = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"syncgroupname");
                            readSyncgroup(parser);
                            // employee.setName(text);
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return employees;
    }

    /** Process Capital tag in the xml data */
    private void readSyncgroup(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "syncgroup");
        parser.nextTag();
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your only checking the root Node,not the node inside it,you need to loop to find whether a node is inside you root node

**For First `KEY_ITEM` value will be `labels` and then do it again with `syncgroupsettings` to get the branch elements ,Similarly inside loop KEY_ID will be branch name like for first time it will be `label` then `syncgroupset` **

```
  XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                list.add(map);
            }
```

Check this Tutorial : [Parsing Xml in Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for the response Rajan. Could you please elaborate it

Comment: Hi Rajan, the problem is, im getting first key item as xml